# Vertically align Text to middle of an image

Tags: html, css

I've got a list with a couple of list items containing text.
I'm adding an image to each list item using the :before pseudo.
The image is noticeably bigger than the text, so how can I align the text or image in the middle?

Thank you

-

**What I currently see**

[image]

**What I want to achieve**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="stats">
    <li class="messages">2</li>
    <li class="sales">15</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.stats {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.stats .messages:before {
  content: url(../images/messages.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.stats .sales:before {
  content: url(../images/basket.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
.stats li { line-height: 22px; }
```

... where 22px is the height of yours icons.

Comment: Didnt work for me, already resolved my question anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to try this.

`<ul class="stats">
    <li><img src="../images/messages.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">2</li>
    <li><img src="../images/basket.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">15</li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

use `.stats li{ line-height: [height of image ]; }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think because im adding the images using 'content' I can't apply any rules to them.

Comment: Didnt work for me, already resolved my question anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ive just found a way to do this. Cant believe I didn't try this before posting.

```
    .stats .messages:before {
        content: url(../images/messages.png);
        opacity: 0.2;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your styles as well as html, try this

```
<style>
.stats {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.stats .messages:before {
  content: url(../images/messages.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
  float:left;
}
.stats .sales:before {
  content: url(../images/basket.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

</style>

<ul class="stats">
    <li class="messages"><div style="margin-top:1px;float:left;">2</div></li>
    <li class="sales"><div style="margin-top:1px;float:left;">15</div></li>
</ul>
```